# Codeigniter - change uri segments

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

The project was developed few years ago and now we need to add custom uri segment to all url. for example now we have

`www.address.com/blog/how-does-it-sound`

and we need to change it to

`www.address.com/ru/blog/how-does-it-sound`

but the uri segment `/ru/` should be available only when russian language is selected. So the question is - how to do something like that global?

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('user_lang') && $this->session->userdata('user_lang') == 'ru' ){
     $this->uri->segment(1) = $this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

I hope you will understand what I need.
I found a class in core, but I'm not sure how to edit it properly.

Comment: as I said in the question - this is not default url. It will be availble only when russian lang is selected (stored in session)

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier) library

Comment: are you sure this lets me to continue anyway even without additional uri segment in the link?

Comment: yes, it is designed to do the same

Comment: @Rajatp I don't think that is a great solution, the one mentioned above is much more effective. I gues